# in place upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.10, 20.04

I have tried to do an in place upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 but the manager isnt findding any updates it just says my system is up to date. Will the GUI based in place upgrade for 19.10 come in the next few days?

Comment: Show us the complete output of `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: How did you try to upgrade?

Comment: david@david-desktop:~$ `do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.`

Comment: Trying to upgrade 19.10 to 20.04 after following the answer below I get the message
"Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."

However the software updater tells me the software is up to date.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Then reboot

Make sure the update-manager-core is installed

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core -y
```

After this issue the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If the command says that there is no new release available and you still want to go ahead with the upgrade to the development release, you can use the the -d option. So enter this into terminal:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

You should be asked to continue with the upgrade. Follow the prompts and you should upgrade to 20.04!